# Keyboard trouble after upgrading to 10.12.4

Tags: keyboard, macos

Since upgrading to 10.12.4 on my mid-2011 MacBook Air, combinations of the left <kbd>cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, and <kbd>Q</kbd> have stopped working. The <kbd>Z</kbd> doesn't work at all.

I have tried to reset keyboard shortcuts and booted into safe mode to test, but neither have helped recover the function of these keys. Any ideas?

Comment: test using an external keyboard - the proximity of those 4 keys would suggest hardware failure

Comment: very odd, but after about a week the use of the keys returned